# How to display the item in the combo box when the item is selected in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I need to display the element in combo box's text box only when the element is selected other wise it should be blank in Pyqt5.
Say I added elements like Apple, orange, grapes and mango in the pyqt5 combo box.
Usually the element apple appear in combo box's text box with out selection. But I need the element to be displayed only after i select this item or any element. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: you can use `.setVisible(False)` or `.setEnable(False)` of the `QComboBox` at start and pass one of them to True when needed

Comment: @ymmx that's not what the OP is asking: they want to show a "clear" combo box that only displays the selected item when an item has been actually selected. As suggested in the given answer, `setCurrentIndex(-1)` is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the QComboBox to be empty until an item is selected from the drop down box, you can use `.setCurrentIndex(-1)`.